# Does SQL Server accept special characters?

Tags: sql-server, special-characters

Does SQL Server handle ASCII codes such as NUL, LF (line feed), CR (carriage return), space, etc? I would like to know because I have a file from mainframe that contains special characters which I need to export to SQL Server as a text file. When I view the records (at the back end as hex code) in SQL Server I want to see those special characters as they were entered.

Is this possible, and do I have to do anything special to have SQL Server maintain those characters?

Comment: This is a good question. Any special considerations for SQL literals would be good to know too.

Answer (score 1):

It just stores them.